# Rails adding new pages to exsisting scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I used scaffold and created a controller model and view part and then I wanted to add a new page eg:search to it so I created search.html.erb in the

```
`views/myview/search.html.erb`
```

and in the routes.rb I added like this

```
 resources :myview ,:collection => {:search => :get}
```

and in controller I added a action def search end .. but when I go to localhost:3000/myapp/myview/develop I get an error

```
Missing template myview/show, application/show with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "/path/app/views" * "/home/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/devise-3.4.0/app/views"
```

I don't want a show page how do I fix this? I want to show my search.html.erb page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how you should declare your routes:

```
resources :myview do
  collection do
    get :search
  end
end
```

As you typed `localhost:3000/myapp/myview/develop`, Rails recognizes it as `/myview/:id` and it is expected behaviour. If you want to add additional `develop` action, then declare it within `routes.rb` first.